# Redirect url containg a specific string to url before question mark

Tags: regex, redirect

I have some urls with the following structure :
https://www.example.com/name-of-a-page?specific_string-anything
I would like to redirect such urls to :
https://www.example.com/name-of-a-page
In other words, I would like to redirect urls containing a specific string, to the part of url located before the question mark.
I thank you in advance for any help in this matter.
Patrick

Comment: Which scripts/languages do you want to use? What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

A simple regex to get matching that part would be `[^\?]+(?=\?)`.

I can't give you any other information because I don't know what language you like to use.

#### EDIT:

According to the new information this should work in the `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```

#### EDIT 2:

According to the latest information ;) the code should be this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^specific_string.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you Siphalor. Sorry to have not been specific enough. I would like to add a directive in the htaccess file in order to redirect https://www.example.com/name-of-a-page?specific_string-anything to https://www.example.com/name-of-a-page. The so called "specific-string" has a fixed value. The so called "name-of-a-page" is different from one url to another.

Comment: Thank you again Siphalor. I cannot see the "specific_string" in the RewriteCond line. How does that directive can target only the urls containing that specific_string ? I apologize if I was not accurate enough in my request.

Comment: @user3278588 Updated it ;)

Comment: Thank you again Siphalor and Happy New Year ! The Edit 2 redirection properly redirect https://www.example.com/name-of-a-page?specific_string to https://www.example.com/name-of-a-page. But it seems that it does no redirect https://www.example.com/name-of-a-page?specific_string-anything to https://www.example.com/name-of-a-page. Would you know how to also redirect the url containing -anything after the specific_string ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add an `.*` between the `specific_string` and the `$` - Updated second edit.

Comment: Thank you again. Indeed I forgot an .* Sorry for my mistake.