# How to redirect or rewrite url with question mark and hashtag?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I would to either Redirect or Rewrite previous site URLs to related new site URLs, through the `.htaccess` file.

For some other reasons, this is already in the `.htaccess` file the here below code :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I would like to Redirect or Rewrite as follows :

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?pages/oldpage#part
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/newpage/
```

To make this Redirection or Rewrite, I do not know what to add in the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Is the fragment identifier (the part after the `#`) necessary in order to identify which page to redirect to? Or is just the query string `pages/oldpage` necessary?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pages/oldpage$
RewriteRule ^index\.php /newpage [QSD]
```

- Capture the query string using `RewriteCond` matching it **only** with `pages/oldpage` from start till end.
- Use `RewriteRule` to match your `REQUEST_URI`, which is `index.php` in `http://www.example.com/index.php?pages/oldpage` and then redirect it to `/newpage` which is effectively `http://www.example.com/newpage` discarding the query string using [QSD](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd).

Comment: Adding some description would be helpful

Comment: @Swanand Updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**A1**: One should be able to use usual [rewrite rules for query string](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pages/oldpage$
RewriteRule ^/index\.php /newpage/?
```

---

**A2**: The short answer for `#part` - it is not possible. But not because of Apache HTTPD behavior.

The part after `#` is called *fragment* in the [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5). A user agent (AKA browser) will NEVER send it and your server will NEVER receive a URI/URL with a fragment.

It is the responsibility of the user agent to resolve the fragment ([RFC 3986, section 3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5)):

> As
> such, the fragment identifier is not used in the scheme-specific
> processing of a URI; instead, the fragment identifier is separated
> from the rest of the URI prior to a dereference, and thus the
> identifying information within the fragment itself is dereferenced
> **solely by the user agent**, regardless of the URI scheme.

Comment: The OP's example also contains a query string.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I checked the given re-write rule on pages where I have no hashtag. But the old page http://www.example.com/index.php?pages/oldpage is re-written in http://www.example.com/?pages/oldpage. Did I make anything wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the matter by the hereafter rewriting :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pages/oldpage
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/newpage/? [R=301,L]
```

Thank you again to every one for helping

Comment: So, the "hashtag" wasn't significant in the end after all? This would then seem to be the same as [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48020220/redirect-url-containg-a-specific-string-to-url-before-question-mark)?